# Why am I getting an extra increment in my newbie code?

Tags: python, dictionary, reference, slice, increment

New Python coder here, with a decent amount of c# experience. I'm trying to complete this exercise from Automate the Boring Stuff with Python:

> Chess Dictionary Validator In this chapter, we used the dictionary
>   value {'1h': 'bking', '6c': 'wqueen', '2g': 'bbishop', '5h': 'bqueen',
>   '3e': 'wking'} to represent a chess board. Write a function named
>   isValidChessBoard() that takes a dictionary argument and returns True
>   or False depending on if the board is valid. A valid board will have
>   exactly one black king and exactly one white king. Each player can
>   only have at most 16 pieces, at most 8 pawns, and all pieces must be
>   on a valid space from '1a' to '8h'; that is, a piece can’t be on space
>   '9z'. The piece names begin with either a 'w' or 'b' to represent
>   white or black, followed by 'pawn', 'knight', 'bishop', 'rook',
>   'queen', or 'king'. This function should detect when a bug has
>   resulted in an improper chess board.

My current solution is as follows,

```
testBoard00 = {'1h': 'bking', '6c': 'wqueen', '2g': 'bbishop', '5h': 'bqueen', '3e': 'wking'}

testBoard01 = {'1a': 'brook', '1b': 'bknight', '1c': 'bbishop', '1d': 'bqueen', '1e': 'bking', '1f' : 'bbishop', '1g' : 'bknight', '1h' : 'brook',
               '2a': 'bpawn', '2b' : 'bpawn', '2c': 'bpawn', '2d' : 'bpawn', '2e': 'bpawn', '2f' : 'bpawn', '2g': 'bpawn', '2h' : 'bpawn',
               '8a': 'wrook', '8b': 'wknight', '8c': 'wbishop', '8d': 'wqueen', '8e': 'wking', '8f' : 'wbishop', '8g' : 'wknight', '8h' : 'wrook',
               '7a': 'bpawn', '7b' : 'bpawn', '7c': 'bpawn', '7d' : 'bpawn', '7e': 'bpawn', '7f' : 'bpawn', '7g': 'bpawn', '7h' : 'bpawn',}

testBoard02 = {'1a': 'brook', '1b': 'bknight', '1c': 'bbishop', '1d': 'bqueen', '1e': 'bking', '1f' : 'bbishop', '1g' : 'bknight', '1h' : 'brook',
               '2a': 'bpawn', '2b' : 'bpawn', '2c': 'bpawn', '2d' : 'bpawn', '2e': 'bpawn', '2f' : 'bpawn', '2g': 'bpawn', '2h' : 'bpawn',
               '8a': 'wrook', '8b': 'wknight', '8c': 'wbishop', '8d': 'wqueen', '8e': 'wking', '8f' : 'wbishop', '8g' : 'bpawn', '8h' : 'wrook', # Extra pawn instead of second Knight!
               '7a': 'wpawn', '7b' : 'wpawn', '7c': 'wpawn', '7d' : 'wpawn', '7e': 'wpawn', '7f' : 'wpawn', '7g': 'wpawn', '7h' : 'wpawn',}

testBoard03 = {'1a': 'brook', '1b': 'bknight', '1c': 'bbishop', '1d': 'bqueen', '1e': 'bking', '1f' : 'bbishop', '1g' : 'bknight', '1h' : 'brook',
               '2a': 'bpawn', '2b' : 'bpawn', '2c': 'bpawn', '2d' : 'bpawn', '2e': 'bpawn', '2f' : 'bpawn', '2g': 'bpawn', '2h' : 'bpawn',
               '8a': 'wrook', '8b': 'wknight', '8c': 'wbishop', '8d': 'wqueen', '8f' : 'wbishop', '8g' : 'wknight', '8h' : 'wrook', # Missing a king!
               '7a': 'wpawn', '7b' : 'wpawn', '7c': 'wpawn', '7d' : 'wpawn', '7e': 'wpawn', '7f' : 'wpawn', '7g': 'wpawn', '7h' : 'wpawn',}

letters = 'abcdefgh'
numbers = '12345678'

BOARDUNITS = { 'pawn' : 0, 'rook' : 0, 'knight' : 0, 'bishop' : 0, 'queen' : 0, 'king' : 0 }
TOTALUNITS = { 'pawn' : 16, 'rook' : 4, 'knight' : 4, 'bishop' : 4, 'queen' : 2, 'king' : 2 }

def isValidChessBoard(board):

    boardIsValid = True

    for k in board:
        let = str(k[1:]).lower()
        num = str(k[:1]).lower()

        if let not in letters:
            print('INVALID: Letter is not in acceptable range!')
            boardIsValid = false
            return boardIsValid

        if num not in numbers:
            print('INVALID: Numbers are not in acceptable range!')
            boardIsValid = false
            return boardIsValid

        # print('Number is ' + num + ' and Letter is ' + let + '.')

    wPieces = bPieces = BOARDUNITS

    for k in board:
        # print('K is now: ' + str(k) + ' which is equal to ' + board[k])
        #piece = board[k]

        print(str(wPieces['king']) + ' white King(s), ' + str(bPieces['king']) + ' black King(s)')

        if board[k][0] == 'b':
            #print('First character of piece is ' + piece[0])

            if(board[k][1:] in bPieces):
                if(board[k][1:] == 'king'):
                    print('Black king here!')
                #print('[][] Black ' + piece[1:] + ' is in bPieces!')
                print('Before Increment: ' + str(wPieces['king']) + ' white King(s), ' + str(bPieces['king']) + ' black King(s)')
                bPieces[board[k][1:]] += 1
                print('After Increment: ' + str(wPieces['king']) + ' white King(s), ' + str(bPieces['king']) + ' black King(s)')
            #else:
            #   print('#### ' + piece[1] + ' is not found in bPieces.')

        elif board[k][0] == 'w':
            #print('First character of piece is ' + piece[0])

            if(board[k][1:] in wPieces):
                if(board[k][1:] == 'king'):
                    print('White king here!')
                print('[][] White '+ board[k][1:] + ' is in wPieces!')
                wPieces[board[k][1:]] += 1
            else:
                print('#### ' + board[k][1] + ' is not found in wPieces.')
        else:
            print('Playing piece is missing "black" or "white" characteristic.')
            return False


        for k in bPieces:
            #print('We have ' + str(bPieces[k]) + ' Black ' + str(k) + '(s)')
            #print('We have ' + str(wPieces[k]) + ' White ' + str(k) + '(s)')
            if bPieces[k] > TOTALUNITS[k] or wPieces[k] > TOTALUNITS[k]:

                print('INVALID: Too many pieces!')

                boardIsValid = False
    print(str(wPieces['king']) + ' white King(s), ' + str(bPieces['king']) + ' black King(s)')
    if bPieces['king'] <= 0 or wPieces['king'] <= 0:
        print('INVALID: One of our kings is missing.')
        #print('Black kings number: ' + str(bPieces['king']))
        #print('White kings number: ' + str(wPieces['king']))
        boardIsValid = False    

    return boardIsValid

if isValidChessBoard(testBoard03):
    print("Board is valid!")
else:
    print("Board is invalid.")
```

After line 60, seen in the middle of the following code...

```
print('Before Increment: ' + str(wPieces['king']) + ' white King(s), ' + str(bPieces['king']) + ' black King(s)')
                bPieces[board[k][1:]] += 1
                print('After Increment: ' + str(wPieces['king']) + ' white King(s), ' + str(bPieces['king']) + ' black King(s)')
```

...I get an increment to Black Kings as expected, but I also get an increment to White Kings. I'm rather confused. Is there some sort of global variable I'm missing here, or am I just writing gibberish code?

Would really appreciate a second pair of eyes on this one. Thank you in advance, Rev.

Comment: There's a good solution to my problem below, but be aware that there are also errors to be found in my testboards as reproduced above (in case you want to use this code yourself!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the following line:

```
wPieces = bPieces = BOARDUNITS
```

The intent of this statement is to create two coppies of the BOARDUNITS dictionary. Instead, this line assigns both `wPieces` and `bPieces` variables to a reference to the same dictionary object. So, modifying the entries of `wPieces` will also modify `bPieces`, and will also modify `BOARDUNITS`, since all three identifiers point to the same object.

You can instead create a copy of the `BOARDUNITS` object like so:

```
wPieces = BOARDUNITS.copy()
bPieces = BOARDUNITS.copy()
```